# How to use cluster on socket.io-client?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cluster-computing

I want to use cluster on both side (Server and Client). I have got success on server side, but unable to do on client side. I am using node.js on both (Server side and Client side).

I am using below code on server side

```
var express = require('express'),
        cluster = require('cluster'),
        sio = require('socket.io');
var port = 3000,
        num_processes = require('os').cpus().length;
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    var app = new express();
    var server = app.listen(port),
            io = sio(server);
    io.on('connection', function (client) {
        client.on('evnt', function (data) {
            console.log('evnt' + process.pid, data);
        });
    });
}
```

and on client side this one

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
var socket = require('socket.io-client')(url);
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected with ', url);
    setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit('evnt', {sham: 'sakdf'});
    }, 500)
});
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('Disconnected');
});
```

Comment: Hi Sham; could you show the code you've tried so far, and describe how it is not working?

Comment: I am using below code as server    var express = require('express'),
        cluster = require('cluster'),
        sio = require('socket.io');

var port = 3000,
        num_processes = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    var app = new express();
    var server = app.listen(port),
            io = sio(server);
    io.on('connection', function (client) {
        client.on('evnt', function (data) {
            console.log('evnt' + process.pid, data);
        });
    });
}

Comment: and  for client this one.   var url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
var socket = require('socket.io-client')(url);
socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected with ', url);
    setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit('evnt', {sham: 'sakdf'});
    }, 500)

});
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('Disconnected');
});

Comment: Hi Sham; when you add more information, you should edit your question to include the new information. That way, anybody can read it most easily without having to search through all the comments too.

Comment: thanks @VinceBowdren for guiding me.

Comment: That's looking more understandable. Now, the next step is to explain how you're trying to make it work - and what happens when it goes wrong. For example, do you get an exception on the client side or server side? If not, what investigative techniques have you tried: network recording, or packet sniffing, or using an IDE with a debug mode?

Comment: did you found any solution of this?

Comment: @Apurv I have added answer of this question. Plz see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of cluster module on client side, simply we can create multiple process or child process if needed. We use cluster on server side because we have to bind multiple processes on same IP and port.

Comment: Upvoted! can you kindly elaborate, I am attempting to connect to multiple wss urls to get live ohlc data from each one, are you saying that this process automatically scales across multiple workers on node?

Comment: If you have multiple unique server's URLs then you have to create multiple unique connection. You can use single process if you want. It will not scale automatically. You have to tune your server accordingly. You can create multiple child process if there is no relation of each other.